# python help can't figure out why with one piece of code error (code academy)

Tags: python-2.7

so here is my code

```
a="yes"
b="no"
c=a[0].upper() + a[1:]
d=b[0].upper() + b[1:]
e=a.upper()
f=b.upper()
def shut_down(s):
    if s == a or c or e:
        return "Shutting down..."
    if s == b or d or f:
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return"yeah"
```

so when i call up the function it doesn't execute properly(it doesn't run through all the if statement) i am new to python and don't know why is this but when i redo the work like the following it works as intended

```
a="yes"
b="no"
c=a[0].upper() + a[1:]
d=b[0].upper() + b[1:]
e=a.upper()
f=b.upper()
def shut_down(s):
    if s == a: 
        return "Shutting down..."
    if s== e:
        return "Shutting down..." 

    if s ==c:
        return "Shutting down..."
    if s == b:
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    if s == d:
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    if s == f:
        return "Shutdown aborted!"

else:
    return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```

can anyone tell me why is this happening

Comment: Duplicate of... many, many questions.

Comment: please point them out it would be very much appreciated !   or link me to the right page     thanks!

Comment: The problem is that there isn't any criteria that can be used to effectively search for them; I've just happened to see a lot of them go by in the past few years.

Comment: i see, can you explain why the code is not working as intended :) i have been contemplating on this for few hours now, and it seems to me that with my restricted knowledge about python i can't Figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the expression `s == a or c or e` (and its variations) which doesn't do what you intend.

It is evaluated like this: `(s == a) or bool(c) or bool(e)`. Since `c` and `e` are always "truthy" values (being non-empty strings), the `or` expression ends up always being true.

There are a few alternative solutions:

1. You could distribute out the equality test in your current version of the expression, resulting in `s == a or s == c or s == e`, but that's a lot of repeated text.
2. Another alternative is to use the `in` operator which tests if a value is in a container: `s in (a, c, e)`. That's less typing, but it still does three tests.
3. A better solution would allow you to avoid the multiple tests completely. Instead, you can make a single test that is completely case-insensitive: `s.lower() == a`.

With the third solution, there's no need to calculate the variables `c`, `d`, `e`, or `f` (and you could even put the `"yes"` and `"no"` literals directly in the tests, allowing `a` and `b` to go away too!). It will match a few more input texts (e.g. `"yEs"`), but that's probably a feature, rather than a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue commonly experienced by new programmers; the computer does not behave how one would *expect* it to, but rather how it is *told* to.

The equality comparison is not distributed across all `or` terms, but rather is only performed on only the first. You must provide it in all terms yourself:

```
if s == a or s == c or s == e:
```

Python also has an alternate syntax for this (although operation is not *quite* the same), based on containment checking:

```
if s in (a, c, e):
```

In this case we have only two operands for `in`, and distribution across the tuple elements is not required.

Comment: thank you very much for the alternative way of doing it i felt i am pretty much stuffed in a good way !